# NSController calling function in NSView

Tags: swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to make NSViewControler work with NSView. I can't get `myView` to call any function in myView(NSView).

`myView?.myFunctionName` does not work and for NSView I get a nil error when I try set backgoundColor `(myview?.layer?.backgroundColor = .white)`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak public var myview: NSView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myview?.wantsLayer = true
        myview?.layer?.backgroundColor = .white
        myview?.needsDisplay = true
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            //Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}

import Cocoa

class myView: NSView {
    var backgroundColor: NSColor?
       
     override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        print("draw")
         if let bg = backgroundColor {
           bg.setFill()
           dirtyRect.fill()
         } else {
           super.draw(dirtyRect)
           print("error:\(String(describing: backgroundColor))")
           self.changeBackgroundColor(color: .blue)
        }
     }

    func changeBackgroundColor(color: NSColor) {
      //  print("change background\( bounds.size)")
      //  backgroundColor = color
        var path = NSBezierPath()
        path = NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(origin:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: bounds.size))
       // print("\(String(describing: path))")
        path.close()
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
        setNeedsDisplay(self.bounds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Set your view class to the view in storyboard, then only connect it to your ViewController, it will have the correct class and you can call the function.

Comment: Yes I have all the view class setup in storyboard and link to the viewcontroler. but still get an error massage, that the background was not set. Also I get the functions to work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is anything logged to the console? What is the text of the error?

Comment: I get an error: nil.

Comment: Is that `print("error:\(String(describing: backgroundColor))")`?